# How do I remove a selected option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the Jquery of removing an option after a user selects it.

```
<select id="field4" name="ProductRankingAtHome" style="width: 30%">
    <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select id="field5" name="ProductRankingAtWork" style="width: 30%">
    <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select id="field6" name="ProductRankingInCar" style="width: 30%">
    <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

So, after someone selects "1" from "field4", "1" won't appear in field5-etc..

I tried:

```
$ document.getElementById("field4").addEventListener("change", function (select) {
    if (this.value != "") {
        var select2 = document.getElementById("field5");
        for (var i = 0; i < select2.options.length; i++) {
            if (this.value == select2.options[i].value) {
                select2.options[i] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.remove()` on `options`

```
select2.remove(i); //i is the index of the option value you wish to remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
$("#field4").on('change',function(){
 if(this.value != ''){
   $("#field5 option[value='"+this.value+"']").remove();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("option").on("click",function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    $("option[value='"+value+"']").each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Look at [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4q56/2/)

Comment: I'm trying to do it without having the user click submit. So they scroll select an option in field4, that option is removed from field5

Answer (score 0):

Going along with what everyone else said. This is removing the first item in the ddl after selected change to simulate a placeholder

```
 $('#ddl').change( function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != '') {
                        var firstChild = $(this).children().eq(0);
                        if (firstChild.attr('value') == '') {

                           firstChild.remove();

                         }
                    }                     
              });
```